# magento2 admin dashboard not loading css and js

Tags: javascript, css, reindex, magento-2.1.9

admin pannel of M2 v2.1.9 not loaded in css and js file means show only html content format.

I'm also run these commond many times but not fix.

- *sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy*
- *php bin/magento setup:di:compile*
- *php bin/magento indexer:reindex*
- *sudo chmod -R 777 var/*

Delete Some Folder too:

- MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/_requirejs
- MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/adminhtml
- MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/frontend

Can anyone guide how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Please check it out if static contain .htaccess file or not if not then paste it from this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/pub/static/.htaccess and do this command

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thanks

Comment: Please guide to exactally what do in this file.

Comment: Hello Please goto Magento2Root/pub/static

Comment: thnks.it worked

Comment: Cool @AnikeshShahi

Comment: Its again problem in frontend.backend working cool but frontend not loaded css file after replacing .htaccess file now

Comment: can you check your base URL ending with slash in core_config_data table?

Comment: yes, base url ending with slash alreday,all pages working correct base url.but only css part not loaded in all pages.

Comment: can you please show me erro

Comment: run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: In default_head_block.xml file under my custom theme.                                       
    <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
       <css src="css/styles.css"/> 
        <css src="css/local-m.css" />
 <css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
<script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
    </head>

Comment: please check default.xml file something is wrong.

Comment: Not getting what is missed in this. I'm using copied to vendor folder to placed in my custom theme .